# elasticsearch move data from local device to cloud ealstic

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

Is there any way to copy all the data of an index from elasticsearch from my computer to cloud elastic ?
i'm working on localhost and now i want to migrate it to cloud.elastic.co
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with [a snapshot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/snapshot-restore.html) of your local cluster into s3, then [a restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-aws-custom-repository.html) of that on Elastic Cloud.

Answer (score -1):

Which cloud provider are you using? If it is AWS OpenSearch, it does not allow remote index operation from local ElasticSearch. Allows if it's an ElasticSearch in the AWS cloud and https is broadcasting.

If the data is critical, you can pull the data and send bulk requests to ElasticSearch in the cloud. I had to do so.

You can write your own application or you can send requests multi-threaded with a tool like Jmeter.